# Cannot find which element was clicked

Tags: jquery

I'm writing short jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#about, #services, #contact").click(function (e) {
        MoveToPage(e);
    })
});
function MoveToPage(e) {
    var del = e.delegateTarget;
    if (del == 'li#about') {
        alert('about')
    } else {
        //dosomething
    }
}
```

The purpose now is to alert which link was clicked. It is not working.Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`event.delegateTarget`](https://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) returns the reference to a element. You can use it to evaluate it with a string literal.

You can use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to check the element against a *selector*.

```
function MoveToPage(e) {
    var del = e.delegateTarget;
    if ($(del).is('li#about')) {
        alert('about')
    } else {
        'something'
    }
}
```

You can also use its `ID` property

```
if(e.delegateTarget.id == 'about')
```

Answer (score 1):

use `e.target.id` to get target id which is clicked

here is js you could use:

```
 $("#about, #services, #contact").click(function (e) {
    MoveToPage(e);
})

function MoveToPage(e) {
   if(e.target.id == 'about')
   {

   }
   else if(e.target.id == 'contact')
   {

   }
   else 
   {

   }
}
```

here is fiddle for you

http://fiddle.jshell.net/UYMxa/280/